# NZEC error on Hackerearth in java

Tags: java

I am getting NZEC exception in java for below code on hackerearth. Can anyone please help?
Added the `try` `catch` block as well

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String S = new String();
            HashMap<Long, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
            S = sc.nextLine();
            int len = sc.nextInt();
            long[] q = new long[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                q[i] = sc.nextLong();
            }
            Long key = (long) 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j <= S.length(); j++) {
                    hm.put(key++, S.substring(i, j));
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (q[i] <= hm.size())
                    System.out.println(hm.get(q[i]));
                else {
                    System.out.println(-1);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236)

Comment: Start with putting `e.printStackTrace();` in the `catch` block, so that you can at least see that an exception occurred if it did.

Comment: actually it has the hidden test cases ...and they are not showing the exception and all

Answer (score 0):

It mostly occurs when negative array index is accesed or the program which we have written takes up more space than the allocated memory for our program to run.